# Equality of equivalence relations that partition the same set.

Tags: equivalence-relations, set-partition

Let $A$ be a set and suppose that $R$ and $R'$ are two equivalence relations in $A$ that induce the same partition $\mathcal{P}$. Prove that $R=R'$.

I am not sure how to start but I want to believe that I need the fundamental theorem of equivalence relations. Any help will be aprecciated.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: You seem to be happy with one of the answers you've got. If after proper consideration you conclude that is the answer that best sorted you out, perhaps you care to accept it as the correct answer. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) and other links in the [Help Center](https://math.stackexchange.com/help) (the link is also a the bottom of the page).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $Q$ is a partion of $A$ then each $x\in A$ is is precisely one block of the partition $Q$.

Now every equivalence relationship on $A$ induces a partition of $A$ so that for any two $x,y \in A$ then $x,y$ are in the same block of $Q$ if and only if $x R y$.

If $R$ and $R'$ both induce the *same* partition $Q$, then for any $x,y\in A$ then $x R y$ if and only if $x,y$ are in the same block.  ANd $x R' y$ if an only if $x,y$ are in the same block.  So $x R y$ if and only if $x R'y$.

So $R = R'$.

This was not meant to be a difficult problem. Once you accept that equivalence relations partition a set, and that a partition induces an equivalence relationship this result is basically inevetible.

=====

It's almost a definition.

Remember that $R \subset A\times A$ so that certain things can be said.

If $(x,y) \in R$ then $x R y$ which means $x,y$ are in the same set of the partition that $R$ induces.  But as $R'$ induces the same partition as $R$ so $x,y$ are in the same set of the partition that $R'$ induces, and $x R' y$ and $(x,y) \in R'$.  So $R \subset R'$.

Likewise if $(x,y) \in R'$ then $x R' y$ and $x, y$ are in the same set of the partitions.  So $x Ry$ and $(x,y) \in R$ and $R'\subset R$.

So $R = R'$.

=====

To be a little more formal:

A partition of $A$ is set of sets, $\mathscr P= \{P_i\}$ were $A = \cup_{P_i\in \mathscr P} P_i$ and the $P_i$ are mutually disjoint.

An equivalence relationship, $R$, on $A$ is a subset of $A\times A$, with the following properties i) Reflexive: for all $x \in A$, $(x,x)\in \mathbb R$.  ii) symmetric: $(x,y) \in R\iff (y,x) \in R$.  iii) Transitive if $(x,y) \in R$ and $(y,z) \in R$ then $(x,z)\in R$.  (We use the notation $x R y$ if $(x,y) \in R$.

It's basic property that: If we define $[x]=\{y\in A| (x,y) \in R\}$ then $\mathscr R = \{[x]|x\in A\}$ is a partition of $A \iff R$ is an equivalence relationship on $A$.

Pf:  If $R$ is an equivalence relationship then for any $x$ we have $(x,x) \in R$ so $x \in [x]$ and so $x\in \cup_{[x]\in \mathscr R}[x]$ so $A\subset \cup_{[x]\in \mathscr R}[x]$. And obviously as $[x]\subset A$, $\cup_{[x]\in \mathscr R}[x]=A$ so $A = \cup_{[x]\in \mathscr R}[x]$.

And if $[x]\cap [y]\ne \emptyset$ then there is a $w\in [x]$ and $w\in [y]$.  But then $(x,w)\in R, (y,w)\in R$ and reflexivity, symmetry, transitivity assures $(x,x),(y,y),(w,w), (w,x),(w,y), (x,y), (y,w) \in R$.  And $[x]=\{z\in A|(x,z)\in R\}$ but if $(x,z)\in R$ then $(y,x)\in R$ so $(y,z)\in R$ so $[x]\subset [y]$ and vice versa.  So $[x]=[y]$.  So the $[x]\in \mathscr R$ are disjoint.

So $\mathscr R$ is a partition.

The reverse direction is just as easy to show.

......

So to the question.

If $R$ and $R'$ are equivalence relations that evoke the same partition, $\mathscr Q$.

Then if $W\in \mathscr Q$ then there is an $x\in A$ where  $W= \{y\in A|(x,y)\in R\}= \{y\in A|(x,y)\in R'\}$ and we can denote this partition $[x]$.

So $(x,y) \in R\implies y\in [x] \implies (x,y) \in R' \implies y\in [x]\implies (x,y)\in R$.

So $(x,y)\in R\iff (x,y)\in R'$ so $R=R'$.

Comment: How can you be sure that x,y are in the same set of the partition that R' induces?

Comment: "How can you be sure that x,y are in the same set of the partition that R' induces?"  There is only one partion..  If $x,y$ are in the same block they are in the same block.  If the partion is induced by $R$ then $x,y$ are in the same block iff $x R y$.  And if the partition is induced by $R'$ then $x,y$ are in the same block iff $x R' y$.  So if the partition is induced by $R$ *and* by $R'$ then $x Ry \iff xR'y$.  This is actually an almost trivial result.

Answer (score 1):

This will be more of an indication rather than a full answer (let me know if you need more details), but still a very explicit one. There is indeed a fundamental theorem at work here, namely the following one:

> **Theorem**. Let $A$ be an arbitrary set. There exist the natural maps:

$$\Phi: \mathscr{Eq}(A) \to \mathscr{Part}(A) \\ \Phi(R)=A/R$$

together with

$$\Psi: \mathscr{Part}(A) \to \mathscr{Eq}(A) \\ \Psi(\mathscr{P})=\bigcup_{X \in \mathscr{P}} (X \times X)$$

which are **mutual inverses**.

Comment: In other words, what we have is a one-to-one correspondence between partitions and equivalence relations in A?

Comment: @ManuelOsuna: precisely, that is the explicit content of the ''fundamental theorem of equivalence relations'' you were briefly referring to. Furthermore, by equipping each of the sets above (of equivalences on and respectively partitions of $A$) with appropriate order relations (inclusion in the case of equivalences, ''being coarser than'' in the case of partitions), the two maps above become isomorphisms of ordered sets.

Comment: I now have a clear idea on how to write the proof. Thanks for being elaborate!

Answer (score 1):

Use that $x \sim y$ if and only if $x$ and $y$ are in the same set of the induced partition.

Answer (score 1):

You have to show $(x,y) \in R$ If and only if $(x,y) \in R'$. In fact, $(x,y) \in R$ If and only if $x$ and $y$ belong to some element of the partition induced by $R$, which is also induced by $R'$, this happens, If and only if $(x,y) \in R'$.

Comment: You have the right idea, but there's a confusion in your answer: $R$ and $R'$ are equivalence relations, so they don't induce equivalences. Maybe you meant "...some kind of partition induced by $R$", which wouldn't be a 'kind' of partition—it would be a partition. Perhaps you should edit your answer.